# using german umlaut for nmap in vim

Tags: vim, encoding, configuration, key

I want to nmap the keyboard key `ö` (german o umlaut) in .vimrc. **How can I do this?**

```
namp ö   f"a
```

This does not work. Looking at my nmaps, I recognized that I have alreday mapped the character `ä` key and suprisingly my key `ö` is recognized as `<f6>`.

```
:nmap
ä      "+dd
<f6>   f"a
```

the .vimrc states at the line for `ä`

```
nmap <M-d>   "+dd
```

I cannot remember how I inserted this key. Any hints?

**Update: The accepted answer solved my problems**

Just for information (OSX):

```sh
file -I ~/.vimrc 
~/.vimrc: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
# linux would be file -i 
vim ~/.vimrc -c 'set encoding?'
"~/.vimrc" [converted] 214L, 6044C
  encoding=utf-8
```

seems so that the iso-8859-1 encoding will be converted in vim to utf-8

```sh
# if you need to convert the file encoding
iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8  < ~/.vimrc > ~/.vimrc.utf8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `<M-d>` resolves to `ä`, `<M-v>` should resolve to `ö`.

Using the literal characters should work as well. However, you need to `:set encoding=...` **before any mappings** in your `~/.vimrc`, and not change it later on, as the mappings are affected by its value. Also, make sure the `.vimrc` file is in an encoding understood by Vim (best `utf-8`); you can explicitly state that via `:scriptencoding utf-8` at the top of your `.vimrc`.

Comment: just curious, Ingo, do you use german keyboard layout for vim editing?

Comment: @Kent: No, as a developer, I cannot live without a US-English keyboard layout (especially for `{}\|`). For the (far fewer) occasions where I write German, I use Vim's digraphs to enter umlaut characters.

Comment: thanx for the Info. same here. Every time my colleague tried to use my keyboard (in eclipse/intellij), they blamed me and say "Oh man!" 100 times. I have HHKB with US-en layout and vim-plugin installed. it is like encrypted keyboard for them... I tried, but using vim with German layout made me crazy.. glad to know that I am not alone.

Comment: sounds like I have to ensure that the file itself is then encoded in the same encoding I will :set. Will be exciting :) my .vimrc is used on osx, linux and windows... hope that works on all... And it came inital vom freebsd...